# How to set rounded corner images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image

I'm new to Flutter. Please anyone guide me to make images like below. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Stack` with `Container`.

Effect:
[image]

Working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 160,
          color: Colors.green,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                left: 60,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: 3,
                    ),
                  ),
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: 3,
                    ),
                  ),
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried but i could not get output like can u pls hlp me

Comment: Do u tried code from my answer?

Comment: yes your code is working fine i got a output like your preview

Answer (score 0):

Please check this below code :

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), // Border width
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
  child: ClipOval(
    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
      size: Size.fromRadius(48), // Image radius
      child: Image.network('https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1845144?v=4', fit: BoxFit.cover),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way also:  `CircleAvatar` Widget

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 20,
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage('{image url}')
)
```